# Django Translation Internationalization and localization: forms, models, tables

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-datatable

I have two questions. How can I translate in forms: a) labels b) Form ValidationErrors ?

```
forms.py

from django import forms
from django.db.models import Max, Min
from .models import Application, FlowRate, WaterFilterSubType, Fineness, Dirt
from .models import DirtProperties, Flange

class InputDataWaterForm(forms.Form):
    '''Application'''
    choices = list(Application.objects.values_list('id','application'))
    application = forms.ChoiceField(choices = choices, initial="1", label="Specify application:")
    ....

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(InputDataWaterForm, self).clean()
        application = cleaned_data.get('application')
    ...

        '''OTHER CONDITIONS if not flowrate ...'''
        if not (flowrate or pressure or dirt or dirtproperties or
            application or fineness or temperature or
            flange or atex or aufstellung or ventil):
            raise forms.ValidationError('PLEASE ENTER THE REQUIRED INFO')
```

How can I translate content of a table in a database? All records eg. product names in a table must be translated.

```
models.py

from django.db import models

'''FILTER PROPERTIES LIKE COLOR'''
class FP_sealing(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField('Material Sealing', max_length=10)
    descr = models.CharField('Description', max_length=200, default="")
    def __str__(self):
        return("Seal: " + self.value)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Translations are normally done with [Django's translation framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/). For eager translations, one uses [**`gettext`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.gettext), for lazy translations (translations that should be calculated when rendered), one uses [**`gettext_lazy`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.gettext_lazy). You can for example translate your application with:

```
from django import forms
from django.db.models import Max, Min
from .models import Application, FlowRate, WaterFilterSubType, Fineness, Dirt
from .models import DirtProperties, Flange
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class InputDataWaterForm(forms.Form):
    '''Application'''
    choices = list(Application.objects.values_list('id','application'))
    application = forms.ChoiceField(choices = choices, initial="1", label=_("Specify application:"))
    # …

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(InputDataWaterForm, self).clean()
        application = cleaned_data.get('application')
        # …

        '''OTHER CONDITIONS if not flowrate …'''
        if not (flowrate or pressure or dirt or dirtproperties or
            application or fineness or temperature or
            flange or atex or aufstellung or ventil):
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('PLEASE ENTER THE REQUIRED INFO'))
```

For choice values in models, as is specified in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types):

> ```
> from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
>
> class Student(models.Model):
>
>     class YearInSchool(models.TextChoices):
>         FRESHMAN = 'FR', _('Freshman')
>         SOPHOMORE = 'SO', _('Sophomore')
>         JUNIOR = 'JR', _('Junior')
>         SENIOR = 'SR', _('Senior')
>         GRADUATE = 'GR', _('Graduate')
>
>     year_in_school = models.CharField(
>         max_length=2,
>         choices=YearInSchool.choices,
>         default=YearInSchool.FRESHMAN,
>     )
>
>     def is_upperclass(self):
>         return self.year_in_school in {
>             self.YearInSchool.JUNIOR,
>             self.YearInSchool.SENIOR,
>         }
> ```

Then you can run the [**`makemessages`** command [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-makemessages) to make translation files:

```
django-admin makemessages --locale=de_DE
```

Django will then make `*.po` files where you can define the translations for the strings you defined.

Then you can use the [**`compilemessages`** command [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-compilemessages) to compile these translation files to `*.mo` files:

```
django-admin compilemessages --locale=de_DE
```

Comment: and my second question please. Which tools are available to translate content (a text field) of a table within a database? Eg. translation / localization of an online shop. The names of products and their descriptions must be tranlated. Thank you.

Comment: @cegthgtlhj: you pass it through the `_(..)` as well. But then you will need to add the translations to the `*.po` files yourself, since Django can know exactly what values should be translated. That being said, if you have choices, then you normally use `_(..)` over the *value* part of the 2-tuples. Such that the translation is done by Django.

Comment: I means such a case, please:

`view.py

qset = Products.objects.all()

Template.html

{% for i in qset %} 
   {{ i.product_name }} `
How can I translate such table values?
Thank you

Comment: @cegthgtlhj: well since the values are arbitrary, you will need to make some extra models that store the product name in different languages. See for example https://goodcode.io/articles/django-multilanguage/